# Allow more than 5 tags if red tags are used

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tags

As many of you should know that using a more than 5 tags simultaneously on the single question isn't possible:

> [image: no more than 5 tags]

Hence once a moderator decides to add a red tag (e.g. any of [status-...]) on the question with 5 tags, they need to think which tag to remove, like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/325574/revisions):

> [image: important tag is removed]

Such type of action reduces the author intent and make tag filtering less efficient. Mod should decide which tag is less relevant to the question before delete them.

So, my suggestion is to allow to use more than 5 tags on the question if there're red tags exist.

Comment: As a moderator, this generally hasn't really been an issue >_>

Comment: Shog did comment somewhere that the limit can be bypassed by a dev...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek what do you mean? Can you put a more than 5 tags on the question?

Comment: We've rarely needed to pop a tag, and usually its not a 'big' deal

Comment: @Shadow the old FR is declined without an explanation from the staff

Comment: The answer gives enough explanation, the staff declining probably didn't see any reason to add anything. This is exactly the same request, so no point leaving it open IMO, if at some point SE will change their mind, there's the original request.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars different times - different decisions. I think it's normal and allowed to re-request old declined features. The suggested one was asked 4+ years ago, before SE acquisition by Protus.

Comment: Well  you can always edit the post, explain this there, and it would be sent for Reopen review.